# data is not inserting into database using php in angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-controller="controller" ng-app="app">
    username:<input type="text" placeholder="*username"  ng-model="user"><br><BR>
    password:<input type="password" placeholder="*password" ng-model="pass" ><br><BR>
Email:&emsp;<input type="email" placeholder="*email"  ng-model="email"><br><BR>
<div align="center">
<input type="submit" value="register" ng-click="insert()">
<input type="button" value="Back" >
    </div>


    <script>
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("controller", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.insert = function() {
        $http.post(
            "insert.php", {
                'user':$scope.user,
                'pass':$scope.pass,
                'email':$scope.email
            }).then(function(response){
                    console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
                },function(error){
                    alert("Sorry! Data Couldn't be inserted!");
                    console.error(error);

                });
            }
        });
</script>
    </html>
```

.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "students");
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
if(count($info) > 0) {

            $user = $data->user;
            $pass = $data->pass;
            $email=$data->email;

    $query = "INSERT INTO students(username, password, email) VALUES('".$user."','".$pass."','".$email."')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        echo "Insert Data Successfully";
    }
    else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
?>
```

data is not inserting into the table and no errors on console...what is the error in the code..gone through many of the videos but unable to find it..I am using mysql workbench 6.3 v..anyone could you please help me

Comment: make sure your db name students and table name students and getting data.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to MySQL Injection, please consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). Go and read this [manual page on MySQLi error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: I guess `$data` should be `$info` ?

Answer (score 0):

`$data` variable is not declared. it should be `$info`

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "students");
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
if(count($info) > 0) {

            $user = $info->user;
            $pass = $info->pass;
            $email=$info->email;

    $query = "INSERT INTO students(username, password, email) VALUES('".$user."','".$pass."','".$email."')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        echo "Insert Data Successfully";
    }
    else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thnq...but no change

Comment: print the `$info` variable and post the result

Comment: that means post values are not passing to the php script. can u look the chrome network tab and check whether the post body is passing.

Comment: ANYONE CAN YOU HELP ME WITH THIS ISSUE ###REQUIRED

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Add this two lines in your php file.  This will allow you to share **cross-origin resource sharing**.

Comment: There are no cross-origin errors in the console. Don't think that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

in insert query your not getting any data.

```
<?php
     $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "students");
     $info = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
     if(count($info) > 0) {

               $user = $info['user'];
                $pass = $info['pass'];
                $email=$info['email'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO students(username, password, email) VALUES('".$user."','".$pass."','".$email."')";

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
            echo "Insert Data Successfully";
        }
        else {
            echo "Failed";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: @lavanya: is this helpfull??